# I have a problem setting and accessing variables in devops pipeline (yaml)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have a Azure DevOps pipeline template that is used for deploying a Arm template. Its also meant to parse the ARM template outputs into Devops variables that should be accessible throughout the pipeline run. But i have problem with setting the variable and accessing it.

Here is a print from the run where we can see the output from the template. It's an array containing strings.

[image: Print from pipeline run showing the variable we are trying to use]

When i attempt to access it in azure powershell script i do this and everything works well.

```
$outputJson = $deployment.outputs | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host "print: $output"
```

[image: Print output after converting to Json]

So im able to print the output. But after that i want to set a variable that i can use in the pipeline run:

Here is my problem, im trying to set the variable here like this: (Tried some different ways)

```
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputTest;isOutput=true]$outputJson"
```

Here is some examples of my syntax when trying to access the variable.

```
Write-Host "print var test1: $outputTest"
Write-Host "print var test2: $(outputTest)"
Write-Host "print var test3: ${{ $variables.outputTest }}"
Write-Host "print var test4: '${{ $variables.outputTest }}'"
```

but what ever i do i do the printed output is empty. I feel so stupid.. haha
Any ideas?

Additional information:

This is the structure of the yaml file where the commands take place

```
steps:
  - script: |
      echo parameters.serviceconnection - ${{parameters.serviceconnection}}
      echo resourceGroup - ${{parameters.resourceGroup}}
      echo resourceGroupLocation - ${{parameters.resourceGroupLocation}}
      echo overrideParameters - ${{parameters.overrideParameters}}
    displayName: 'arm-template.yml - Variable list'

task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: "PowerShell template deploy"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
      scriptType: InlineScript
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
      inline: |
    "my code"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not mistaken, the reason you are not seeing the variable is because when you are using `isOutput=true` the task/step itself would need to be referenced.

This flag is important for passing variables/data between stages & jobs, but can be skipped for tasks within the same job.

I will give you 2 alternatives on how you should be able to solve it.

**Option 1**

Remove the `isOutput=true` from `Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputTest;isOutput=true]$outputJson"`

This should make it into a regular variable and can there after be called by `$(outputTest)`.

Please note that this variable only exists within the same `job` and is only known for the agent running the `job`. It can be referenced within the same `job`, but it cannot be referenced/called anywhere else thereafter.

**Option 2**

If you keep `isOutput=true` you would need a way to reference the task itself:

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: "PowerShell template deploy"
    name: NameOfMyTask
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
      scriptType: InlineScript
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
      inline: |
       "your code"
```

By adding `name: NameOfMyTask` while keeping `isOutput=true` you should be able to reference it by `$(NameOfMyTask.outputTest)`

*Passing it to another job*

With `isOutput=true` it can also be referenced in another `job` using the following example:

```yaml
- job: MySecondJob
  dependsOn: [MyFirstJob] # This is your job where you set the variable with isOutput=true
  variables:
    myOutput: $[ dependencies.MyFirstJob.outputs['NameOfMyTask.outputTest'] ]

  steps:

  - pwsh: |
      Write-Output $(myOutput)
```

With `isOutput=true` it can also be referenced in another `stage` using the following example:

*Passing it to another stage*

```yaml
- stage: MySecondStage
  dependsOn: [MyFirstStage] # This is your stage where you set the variable with isOutput=true
  variables:
    myOutput: $[ stageDependencies.MyFirstStage.MyFirstJob.outputs['NameOfMyTask.outputTest'] ]
  
  jobs:

  - job: MySecondJob

    steps:

    - pwsh: |
        Write-Output $(myOutput)
```

The reason the `dependsOn` is needed is because `$[]` is a runtime expression, and if it would not await the first stage/job/step to be completed and hence the variable set, it would lead to an empty value/null for the variable.

Hope you can solve it using the provided information, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#specify-variables) correctly you always have key/value pair for a pipeline variable, meaning that you can't just convert your object to a pipeline variable. If you would google on parsing arm/bicep output you can find some examples on converting the arm output.

For example, in bash:

```bash
      deploymentOutput=$(az deployment group show \
        --resource-group $(rgName) \
        --name $(vnetName)-$deploymentSuffixAttempt \
        --query properties.outputs | jq -c 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value.value]')
      while IFS=$'\n' read -r c; do
        outputname=$(echo "$c" | jq -r '.[0]')
        outputvalue=$(echo "$c" | jq -r '.[1]')
        echo "Log variabele: $outputname : $outputvalue"
        declare $outputname=$outputvalue 
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$outputname;isoutput=true]$outputvalue"
      done <<< "$deploymentOutput"
```

Or in powerhshell:

```
[CmdletBinding()] 
param ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [string]$ArmOutputString, 
    [Parameter()] 
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [switch]$MakeOutput 
) 
Write-Output "Retrieved input: $ArmOutputString" 
$armOutputObj = $ArmOutputString | ConvertFrom-Json 
$armOutputObj.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { 
    $type = ($_.value.type).ToLower() 
    $keyname = $_.Name 
    $vsoAttribs = @("task.setvariable variable=$keyName") 
    if ($type -eq "array") { 
        $value = $_.Value.value.name -join ',' ## All array variables will come out as comma-separated strings 
    } elseif ($type -eq "securestring") { 
        $vsoAttribs += 'isSecret=true' 
    } elseif ($type -ne "string") { 
        throw "Type '$type' is not supported for '$keyname'" 
    } else { 
        $value = $_.Value.value 
    } 
 
    if ($MakeOutput.IsPresent) { 
        $vsoAttribs += 'isOutput=true' 
    } 
    $attribString = $vsoAttribs -join ';' 
    $var = "##vso[$attribString]$value" 
    Write-Output -InputObject $var 
}
```

Note that these are just examples and require sometimes some extra's on your deployment as well.

Once you have converted them successful, you can access them in powershell as system variables:

```
Write-Host "print var test1: $env:outputTest"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some noteworthy points, you may not have encountered them, but important

1. Setvariable should set the only string variables, not array, oneline string is prefer
2. Use the setvariable variable in another step, it will not take effect in current step.
3. Array data type in yaml, bicep, powershell script may be treated differently.

I have coded an example to read the arm template output variables.

`test.bicep`

```
param privateTypes array = [
  'blob'
  'file'
  'queue'
  'table'
]

output myoutput array = privateTypes
```

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
parameters:
- name: serviceconnection
  type: string
  default: 'xxx'
- name: resourceGroup
  type: string
  default: 'xxx'
- name: resourceGroupLocation
  type: string
  default: 'eastus'
# - name: overrideParameters
#   type: object
#   default: 'xxx'

jobs:
# Set an output variable from job A
- job: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo parameters.serviceconnection - ${{parameters.serviceconnection}}
      echo resourceGroup - ${{parameters.resourceGroup}}
      echo resourceGroupLocation - ${{parameters.resourceGroupLocation}}
    displayName: 'arm-template.yml - Variable list'

  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    name: armDeployment
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceconnection}}
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
      ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
      Inline: |
        New-AzResourceGroup -Name ${{parameters.resourceGroup}} -Location ${{parameters.resourceGroupLocation}} -Force

        $deploy = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name 'testDeployment' -ResourceGroupName ${{parameters.resourceGroup}} -TemplateFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\test.bicep

        $deployOutputString = $deploy.Outputs.myoutput.Value | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

        Write-Host "type is: $($deployOutputString.GetType())"
        Write-Host "string is: $deployOutputString"

        $temp = $deployOutputString | convertFrom-Json
        foreach($item in $temp){
          Write-Host "item is: $item"
        }

        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputTest;isOutput=true]'$deployOutputString'"

  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: testOutputWithString
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "variable type is $($(armDeployment.outputTest).GetType())"
        Write-Host "variable is: $(armDeployment.outputTest)"
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have tested based on your description, we cannot use multi-line json contents (an array of values) to define output variables in a pipeline script; for this, you may test with `$outputString = ($deployment.Outputs.privateTypes.Value | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)` instead, to convert the expected outputs of your ARM template deployment into a oneline string;

To reference the pipeline output variable in downstream pipeline steps/jobs/stages, we need to add `name` (**not** `displayName`) property for the `AzurePowerShell@5` pipeline task. Here is a sample for your reference, which can generate a pipeline output variable with the ARM deployment array outputs and then print the output variable value in downstream step from the same job.

```
parameters:
- name: serviceconnection
  type: string
  default: ARMSvcCnnAutoSubX
- name: resourceGroup
  type: string
  default: rg-armdeployment
- name: resourceGroupLocation
  type: string
  default: 'West US'
- name: overrideParameters
  type: object
  default:
    resourceGroupName: rg-armdeployment
    location: 'West US'
    storageAccountType: Standard_LRS
    storageAccountName: armdeploymentsa

stages:
- stage: Stage_ARMDeploy
  displayName: ARM Template Deployment
  jobs:
  - job: Job_ARMDeploy
    displayName: Traditional job to deploy ARM Template
    steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      name: Step_ARMDeploy
      displayName: Deploy ARM template via Azure PowerShell
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '${{parameters.serviceconnection}}'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          Write-Host parameters.serviceconnection - ${{parameters.serviceconnection}}
          Write-Host resourceGroup - ${{parameters.resourceGroup}}
          Write-Host resourceGroupLocation - ${{parameters.resourceGroupLocation}}
          # Creating hashtable for parameters
          $overrideParameters = @{
              "storageAccountType" = "${{ parameters.overrideParameters.storageAccountType }}"
              "storageAccountName" = "${{ parameters.overrideParameters.storageAccountName }}$(Build.BuildId)"
          }

          Write-Host overrideParameters:
          $overrideParameters
          $resourceGroupName = "${{parameters.resourceGroup}}-$(Build.BuildId)"

          Write-Host Creating new resource group
          New-AzResourceGroup `
            -Name $resourceGroupName `
            -Location "${{parameters.resourceGroupLocation}}"
          
          Write-Host Deploying storage account in the resource group via arm json template
          $deployment = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
            -Name ARMDeployment$(Build.BuildId) `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
            -TemplateFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/JSONTEMPLATES/StorageAccount/StorageAccount.json `
            -TemplateParameterObject $overrideParameters `
            -verbose
          
          Write-Host ARM deployment outputs:
          $deployment.Outputs.privateTypes
          Write-Host Convert outputs into json:
          $outputJson = $deployment.Outputs.privateTypes.Value | ConvertTo-Json
          $outputJson
          #************************************************************************************
          Write-Host Output the single-line string
          $outputString = ($deployment.Outputs.privateTypes.Value | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)
          Write-Host outputSring - $outputString
          Write-Host Defining output variable for downstream steps/jobs/stages
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputTest;isoutput=true]$outputString"
          #************************************************************************************
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "$(Step_ARMDeploy.myOutputTest)"
        # Convert the single-line JSON string back to an array
        $outputArray = '$(Step_ARMDeploy.myOutputTest)' | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host outputArray:
        $outputArray
      displayName: Print output variable value in downstream step from the same job
```

[image]

For usage of output variables across stages and jobs, please refer to [Set variables in scripts - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables)